# Why is my data storing twice in my Firebase Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am new at using Firebase so all advice is welcome.

**What i'm trying to achieve?**

I want to create a player only if the user has not exceeded their team size ("numberOfplayersLimit").
So currently I am using a firebase transaction which first checks that the team has not exceeded their limit "numberOfPlayers", if the team has not exceeded their limit, increment the "numberOfplayersLimit" counter and then add the player to the database as shown below.

**Whats my issue**

I am currently using `.push()` to add the players however it is creating the player twice as shown below as you can see the full name is the same in other records but they have different uids.

Below is a screenshot from my Firebase real-time database JSON structure

[image]

```js
var myUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    
const playerData = {
    fullName:this.state.fullName,
   
};

 //This is where the players are stored 
 const teamplayersref = firebase.database().ref('/teams').child(myUserId).child('/players')


 //Transaction - Team reference path for the TeamPlayers Limit
 const getTeamPlayersLimit = firebase.database().ref('/teams').child(myUserId).child('numberOfplayersLimit');

  getTeamPlayersLimit.transaction(function(numberOfplayersLimit){


        if (numberOfplayersLimit == 11) {
            alert('You have exceed your team size limit, Delete a player from your team or contact us to upgrade your package');
        }

        else 
        {
          
            //increment teamplayers limit
            numberOfplayersLimit = numberOfplayersLimit + 1;
              
 
            teamplayersref.push(playerData);
 
            return numberOfplayersLimit;

        }
    });
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to put an alert() inside of a transaction handler.  Instead you should fail the transaction, and raise the alert after it's finished.  Also keep in mind that transaction handlers are called potentially many times (starting with null as the value at the database), and typically should only modify the data at the location of the transaction.  I suggest adding some logs to see what is actually going on.

Comment: You should not check for ```numberOfplayersLimit == 11```but rather for ```numberOfplayersLimit >= 11```. This includes anything with and above 11. The first does only contain exactly 11.

Comment: @DougStevenson incrementing isn't the issue as it increase by one which is correct. the issue is that when i use .push() it creates the player twice. What would you suggest to  log?

Comment: @Simon Thanks for your help but I have tried this there now and my issue is still occuring

Comment: Log anything at all inside the transaction handle to see how it's executing.  Use a debugging to trace through its execution.  push() is getting called twice, and my first comment is giving you the reason - the handler is getting invoked twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `teamplayersref.push(playerData)` call in your transaction handler is not part of the transaction itself. So if the transaction is retried, you end up calling `teamplayersref.push(playerData)` multiple times, creating a child node for each try.

To generate a new child with unique push ID, use push without an argument to get a new key, and then use that in the `return` value of your transaction. This means that your transaction will have to run on the entire `firebase.database().ref('/teams')` node, since you're modifying both the counter and the players.

```
const teamRef = firebase.database().ref('/teams').child(myUserId);

teamRef.transaction(function(team){
    team = team || { numberOfplayersLimit: 0, players: {} };
    if (team.numberOfplayersLimit == 11) {
        console.error('You have exceed your team size limit, Delete a player from your team or contact us to upgrade your package');
    }
    else  {
        team.numberOfplayersLimit = team.numberOfplayersLimit + 1;
        const newPlayerKey = teamRef.push().key; // this line does not write to the database

        team.players[newPlayerKey] = playerData;

        return team;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I am seeing an error ,"TypeError: Cannot read property 'numberOfplayersLimit' of null" . its occuring on the line where the if statement starts

Comment: It looks like the `team` doesn't exist in that case, so you'll want to check for that.  Honestly, I wrote this without testing it, so it may contain minor errors and it may miss error handling like that.

Comment: unfortnately , .push() is still storing twice. should the value within the function() not be the field I am looking to require if i use const getTeamPlayersLimit = firebase.database().ref('/teams').child(myUserId).child('numberOfplayersLimit'); instead of the your solutions reference?

Comment: My code reads the entire team JSON, and modifies that. It should not create multiple nodes. Are you sure the `teamRef.transaction()` is only called once? Adding a `console.log` before it might show that.

Comment: So when I console.log(numberOfplayersLimit); the first value is null and then it increments to the new value. This may be the reason why it creates to instances of the player

Comment: The first time your transaction handler gets called it is normal for the current value to be null. This is one of the reasons you shouldn't do any side-effects in the handler, as it may (and typically *will*) be called multiple times. You can add a `null` check if you want (I updated my answer with something similar), but my code doesn't write anything to the database that is not part of the transaction, so it *will* not write multiple nodes. --- If you're still having issues, edit your question to show the latest code.

Comment: how would you suggest, I achieve this feature as I'm new to firebase so is using a transaction the best option? I using it within React Native. It seem like it causing more hassle than it should

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code in my answer should work, minus maybe some error checks and syntax problems. Hence: If you're still having issues, edit your question to show the latest code

Comment: funny enough I was searching the internet and found a tweet from you mentioning about ServerValue.increment lol. I have know decided to use it. However your answer is correct, so i will approve it .